# parsing date from string but getting wrong value

Tags: java, string, date

So, I want to compare two dates and I have an if loop to function if one date is after the other. My method:

Start and End Dates are user inputted variables and are in the form Month/Day/Year.

```
String startDate = "02/20/2012";
String endDate = "03/20/2012";

Date startDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(startDate);
Date endDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(endDate);
```

however, startDate1 is showing this: `Mon Feb 20 00:00:00 EST 2012`
and, 
    endDate1 is showing this: `Tue Mar 20 00:00:00 EDT 2012`

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here.

The loop:
    `if (endDate1.after(startDate1)){
         blah blah blah
    }`

Comment: i don't understand. these result seem correct to me. What would you expect?

Comment: Can you explain what you think is wrong with those dates? Because it's not obvious. Note one is in EST and the other in EDT because of daylight savings.

Comment: I was under the assumption that it would change it into a Date format so startDate1 would still be 02/20/2012 but would be in Date Format....I didn't think that it would write it out...

Comment: @user2122268 Instead of assuming, you should have searched StackOverflow for "java date". You would quickly learn that java.util.Date has no time zone yet its `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM's default time zone when generating the string.

Comment: A Date represents a moment in time.  It's not a String - it doesn't have a format of its own.  You are successfully converting your Strings into Dates.  Nothing is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong, that's the default toString() representation format of the Date object in java

Answer (score 0):

Use this to compare two dates.

```
if(startDate1.compareTo(endDate1)>0){
     System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
}else if(startDate1.compareTo(endDate1)<0){
     System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
}else if(startDate1.compareTo(endDate1)==0){
     System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
}else{
     System.out.println("How to get here?");
     }
```

Comment: The OP is using `after` to compare the two dates, which is far more readable than `compareTo`.  Using this code would be a step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

What you specified with `MM/dd/yyyy` is the input format to correctly convert user input to a date. What is "shown" (by the debugger ?) is the output format as returned by the `toString` method.

But the date is actually stored as an integer number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing correct behavior. The java.util.Date object has both a date portion and a time portion. The object has no time zone yet its `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM's default time zone when generating the string.

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use a decent date-time library. For Java, that means either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Joda-Time offers a LocalDate class if you are certain you do not need time or time zone. Caution: Naïve programmers often think they have no need for time or time zone but later regret that decision.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String startInput = "02/20/2012";
String stopInput = "03/20/2012";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" );

LocalDate start = formatter.parseLocalDate( startInput );
LocalDate stop = formatter.parseLocalDate( stopInput );
boolean isStopAfterStart = stop.isAfter( start );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "start: " + start );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println( "isStopAfterStart: " + isStopAfterStart );
```

When run…

```
start: 2012-02-20
stop: 2012-03-20
isStopAfterStart: true
```